# Passing Canvas object (HTML 5)from html page to servlet

Tags: javascript, html, servlets

I am developing an authentication system which is based on images. For these I needed to use the "Canvas" element of HTML5. Now I want to pass this canvas object (which user selects) to the servlet. How may I achieve this? Please help

Comment: I would first wonder if servlets are yet capable of handling HTML 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the Canvas into an inline image, and send the result to the servlet by using a XHR request. This [blog entry](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/) describe how to convert a Canvas to a Base64 encoded image. For the XHR request, [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=xhr) is your friend...